# Can't use Vue.js data property to Trigger gsap F.L.I.P change

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, gsap, flip

I'm playing around with the [GreenSock F.L.I.P plugin](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/Plugins/Flip) and Vue.Js and i stumble on an issue

### What I'm trying

I tried changing the layout with a data property in VueJs instead of a class toggle

### Example/ Code

But I don't know if it could works and why what I have done doesn't

Since you can't add paying greenSock plugins into Stack Overflow snippet I made a codepen to show you the error: https://codepen.io/FreeStab/pen/MWpxEXm

**Here is the working code**

```
changeLayout() {
 //this one works FINE
 const state = Flip.getState(".flex, .bloc"); 
 document.querySelector(".flex").classList.toggle("change");

  Flip.from(state, {
    absolute: true,
    duration: 0.5,
    stagger: 0.1,
    ease: "power1.inOut"
  });
}
```

But when I try to change the layout with a data property that represent the state it doesn't work

```
 changeLayoutWithData() {
  //this one Doesn't works
  const state = Flip.getState(".flex2, .bloc");

  this.flexClass = !this.flexClass;

  Flip.from(state, {
    absolute: true,
    duration: 0.5,
    stagger: 0.05,
    ease: "power1.inOut"
  });
}
```

with my template being like

```
  <div id="app">
    <h1>Click on elements to animate</h1>
    <h2>This works</h2>
    <div class="flex" @click="changeLayout">
      <div class="bloc">1</div>
      <div class="bloc">2</div>
      <div class="bloc">3</div>
    </div>
    <h2>This doesn't</h2>
    <div
      class="flex2"
      :class="{ change: flexClass }"
      @click="changeLayoutWithData"
    >
      <div class="bloc">1</div>
      <div class="bloc">2</div>
      <div class="bloc">3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Could someone explain why is it so ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changes in frameworks are done asynchronously so updates can get batched together. So you need to wait for the DOM to render those changes.

https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2019/01/22/vue-what-is-next-tick/

```
this.flexClass = !this.flexClass;

this.$nextTick(() => {
  Flip.from(state, {
    absolute: true,
    duration: 0.5,
    stagger: 0.05,
    ease: "power1.inOut"
  });        
});
```